# Error al ingresar datos predefinidos

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy desarrollando el ingreso de nuevos usuarios dentro de una empresa de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$estado = 'invactivo';
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
   if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
   $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, pass, email, estado, ufecha) VALUES (:nombre, :pass, :email; :estado, :ufecha)");
   $add->bindValue(':nombre', $_POST['name']);
   $add->bindValue(':pass', md5($_POST['pass']));
   $add->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
   $add->bindValue(':estado', $estado);
   $add->bindValue(':ufecha', $fecha);
   $add->execute();
   echo 'Usuario Registrado';
   } else {
   echo 'Error en el registro';
   }
}
?>

<form method="post">
<label>Enter Username</label>
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off"><br>
<label>Enter Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
<label>Enter Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pass" autocomplete="off"><br>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Registrar">
</form>
```

Base de datos:

```
id(int) | nombre(varchar) | pass(varchar) | email(varchar)  | estado(varchar) | ufecha(date)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | juan            | dw3scws12dwe  | juan@mail.co    | inactive        | 2020-04-17
```

Y cuando hago la prueba tengo este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '; 'invactivo', '2020-04-17')' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\signup\index.php:53 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\signup\index.php(53): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\signup\index.php on line 53

Aclaro que los datos que ingreso desde variables son porque el admin activa a los nuevos usuarios.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en tu consulta estas pasando en la parte de values despues de **:email** un punto y coma en vez de una coma, por eso el error de sintaxis.

```
$add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, pass, email, estado, ufecha) VALUES (:nombre, :pass, :email; :estado, :ufecha)");
```

Debería quedar de esta manera:

```
$add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, pass, email, estado, ufecha) VALUES (:nombre, :pass, :email, :estado, :ufecha)");
```

Comment: Gracias Steven, no lo vi... me estaba volviendo loco pensando que era un dato e hice varios var_dump y bueno... mil gracias!!!!